# Why does my JQuery AJAX request work locally but not when pushed to App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jquery

I am building an app that makes use of Google Wallet In App Payments. It is hosted on google app engine in the python environment.

As part of the wallet transaction a jwt needs to be generated, and I do this by grabbing client side data, sending it serverside for jwt generation via an ajax GET request and then capturing it on the server response. My code works as expected when in my local development environment (running in chrome incognito to avoid cache issues). However when I push the app live and make the request, nothing gets returned and the python method doesn't run.

Appengine logs do show that the request is being seen - it's just not being acted upon.

```
2013-06-18 21:35:01.919 /payments/generate_jwt_token?topup_amount=1&user_token=108700000000000000889 302 51ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
86.1.75.123 - someuser [18/Jun/2013:14:35:01 -0700] "GET /payments/generate_jwt_token?topup_amount=1&user_token=108700000000000000889 HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "http://myapp.appspot.com/me/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36" "myapp.appspot.com" ms=52 cpu_ms=0 app_engine_release=1.8.1
```

If I use postman to make the same request (from my chrome browser), i.e. I send a GET request to

```
http://myapp.appspot.com/payments/generate_jwt_token?topup_amount=1&user_token=108700000000000000889
```

I do get the expected response (just as I do in my local development environment). I only have 1 version of the app on app engine.

I have tried changing the request to a POST request, but experience the same issue - it should throw an error.

The ajax request is as follows:

```
function get_jwt_token_for_user(topup_amount, callback)
{
    console.log("get_jwt_token is running"); // this is printed to console
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: "/payments/generate_jwt_token",
        data: {"topup_amount" : topup_amount, "user_token" : "108700000000000000889"},
        success: function(result) {
            var myObject = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log("myObject"); // none of this is printed when on appengine, but it is when running locally
            console.log(myObject); // none of this is printed when on appengine, but it is when running locally
            if (myObject.jwt_token !== 'None')
            {
                callback(myObject.jwt_token);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(myObject.error);
            }
        },
        failure: function(fail){ 
            console.log("fail");
            console.log(fail);
        }
     });
}
```

Despite all the console.log(s) nothing gets written to console within the ajax request. The function does run however, as I can see the very first console.log get printed to screen.

My questions are:

1. Is this an appengine error/feature, and if so how can I fix it?
2. Am I misusing JQuery ajax, and if so how?
3. Why might this code all work locally, but not when pushed live.

Comment: Why does the log show a status code of 302?  Do you have a redirect on that URL?  That would explain why your method is not being called.

Comment: Try calling the URL using wget with a --max-redirect 0 argument. Then you can see where the redirect is sending you. My bet is you have secured the url and you are being redirected to a login page, though that is only a guess.

Comment: Tim you got it in one. I was just investigating the 302 that Brent pointed out and after a lot of trial and error I discovered that for the url in question I had secure: always in my app.yaml. Thanks for commenting guys - +1s all round :)